# pandas dataframe object to datetime minutes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a csv of Belmont Stakes which is like below

```
Year    Winner   Sire         Time
2016    Creator  Tapit        2:28.51
2015    Pharoah  Pioneerof    2:26.65
2014    Tonalist  Tapit       2:28.52
2013    Palace    Curlin      2:30.70
```

'Time' column is in object format. I want to import my csv in a way, so that it can be seen like below -

```
Year    Winner   Sire         Time(mins)
2016    Creator  Tapit        148.51
2015    Pharoah  Pioneerof    146.65
2014    Tonalist  Tapit       148.52
2013    Palace    Curlin      150.70
```

More precisely, I want my Time columns into minutes. I dont want to transfrom columns after import. I want to transform my data while importing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the vectorised `str` methods to `split` the string and then convert each component to minutes units:

```
In [108]:
df['Time(mins)'] = df['Time'].str.split(':').str[0].astype(float) * 60 \
+ df['Time'].str.split(':').str[1].str.split('.').str[0].astype(float) \
+ df['Time'].str.split('.').str[-1].astype(float)/100
df

Out[108]:
   Year    Winner       Sire     Time  Time(mins)
0  2016   Creator      Tapit  2:28.51      148.51
1  2015   Pharoah  Pioneerof  2:26.65      146.65
2  2014  Tonalist      Tapit  2:28.52      148.52
3  2013    Palace     Curlin  2:30.70      150.70
```

Thanks to the master @Jeff for suggesting using `to_timedelta` to parse this if you reformat the strings to `HH:MM:SS` first:

```
In [115]:
df['timedelta'] = pd.to_timedelta('00:0'+ df['Time'], unit='m')
df

Out[115]:
   Year    Winner       Sire     Time  Time(mins)       timedelta
0  2016   Creator      Tapit  2:28.51      148.51 00:02:28.510000
1  2015   Pharoah  Pioneerof  2:26.65      146.65 00:02:26.650000
2  2014  Tonalist      Tapit  2:28.52      148.52 00:02:28.520000
3  2013    Palace     Curlin  2:30.70      150.70 00:02:30.700000
```

This will give you a `timedelta` dtype which is more useful than just a string IMO as arithmetic operations will work:

```
In [116]:
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 6 columns):
Year          4 non-null int64
Winner        4 non-null object
Sire          4 non-null object
Time          4 non-null object
Time(mins)    4 non-null float64
timedelta     4 non-null timedelta64[ns]
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(3), timedelta64[ns](1)
memory usage: 272.0+ bytes
```

If you want to do the conversion on reading then you can define a custom func and pass this arg to `read_csv`:

```
In [131]:
import io
import pandas as pd

t="""Year    Winner   Sire         Time
2016    Creator  Tapit        2:28.51
2015    Pharoah  Pioneerof    2:26.65
2014    Tonalist  Tapit       2:28.52
2013    Palace    Curlin      2:30.70"""
​
def func(x):
    return float(x.split(':')[0]) * 60 + float(x.split(':')[1].split('.')[0]) + float(x.split('.')[-1])/100
​
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), delim_whitespace=True, converters={'Time':func})
df

Out[131]:
   Year    Winner       Sire    Time
0  2016   Creator      Tapit  148.51
1  2015   Pharoah  Pioneerof  146.65
2  2014  Tonalist      Tapit  148.52
3  2013    Palace     Curlin  150.70
```

Comment: to_timedelta will parse this (may need a leading 0)

Comment: actually I want to import my csv like this. I dont want to transfrom after import. Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: your question didn't state this, you can supply a converter func to `read_csv`, please edit your question with what your csv actually looks like

Comment: I am accepting your answer and also updating my question. Can you please update your answer too ?

Comment: See updated answer, obviously you pass your path to filename and not `io.StringIO` and I don't know what your csv looks like so `delim_whitespace=True` may not be necessary

Comment: Thanks for the both answer :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this might work:

```
df.Time = df.Time.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.split(':'))
df.Time = df.Time.apply(lambda x: int(x[0]) * 60 + float(x[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform time using apply method:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Year":[2016,2017], 
                   "Time":["2:28.51", "2:26.65"],
                   "Winner":["Creator","Tapit"]})
def format_time(s):
    s = s.replace(".",":")
    s = s.split(":")
    s = map(float, s)
    return round(s[0]*60.+s[1]+s[2]/60., 2)
df["Time"] = df["Time"].apply(format_time)
```